# How to properly scale X and Y of point with canvas on top of image

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, scaling

I'm troubled with scaling coordinates for drawing on canvas and can't figure it out.

A bit of what is happening in application.

I have an image and im trying to find and point out the place of image im searching for. It looks like that:

[image]

and I'm searching for this one

[image]

When my code finds a matches it draws a rectangles everywhere where it found something related to template image based on correlation which I can set (for testing purpose it's low). Output looks like that:

[image]

And my issue is that it's clearly scaled wrong and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Some code here:

```
        private void SearchForRunesBtn_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (CharactersListView != null && CharactersListView.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                var result = Compare.compareImageWithTirRune((CharactersListView.SelectedItem as CharacterStash)?.ImageSrc);
                squares(result);
            }
        }

        private void squares(List<System.Drawing.Point> points)
        {

            Cnv.Children.Clear();
            Cnv.Width = StashImage.DesiredSize.Width;
            Cnv.Height = StashImage.DesiredSize.Height;

            var widthScale = StashImage.DesiredSize.Width / StashImage.Source.Width;
            var heightScale = StashImage.DesiredSize.Height / StashImage.Source.Height;
            foreach (var point in points)
            {
                Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
                rect.Width = 10;
                rect.Height = 10;
                rect.StrokeThickness = 1;
                rect.Fill = Brushes.Sienna;                
                Cnv.Children.Add(rect);

                Canvas.SetLeft(rect, point.X * widthScale);
                Canvas.SetTop(rect, point.Y * heightScale);
            }
        }
```

So squares function is basically drawing a rectangle after calculating the scale of images e based on rendered size of my image (DesiredSize) and Source image.

I need that because function which calculate similarity between images operates on original files and view can be stretched which also resize my image.

Here is code for calculating similarity with AForge if that will help anyone

```
internal class Compare
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// It's a test method for overal assumptions with searching image inside image
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="imageSrc"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static List<Point> compareImageWithTirRune(string? imageSrc)
        {
            if (imageSrc == null)
            {
                return new List<Point>();
            }
            Debug.WriteLine("Start - Searching for tir rune");
            DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
            List<Point> result = new List<Point>();


            System.Drawing.Bitmap sourceImage = ConvertToFormat(imageSrc);
            System.Drawing.Bitmap template = ConvertToFormat("Images/CompareEngine/tir.png");

            ExhaustiveTemplateMatching tm = new ExhaustiveTemplateMatching(0.6f);
            // find all matchings with specified above similarity

            TemplateMatch[] matchings = tm.ProcessImage(sourceImage, template);

            foreach (var item in matchings)
            {
                result.Add(new Point(item.Rectangle.X, item.Rectangle.Y));
            }

            Debug.WriteLine("End - Searching for tir rune");
            Debug.WriteLine("Elapsed = " + new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Ticks - start.Ticks).ToString("HH:mm:ss.fffffff") );
            return result;
        }

        public static Bitmap ConvertToFormat(string src)
        {
            Bitmap image = new Bitmap(System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(src));
            PixelFormat format = PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed;
            var bw = image.Clone(new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height), format);
            return bw;
        }
    }
```

There is convertion to 8bbp there for performance reasons but I don't think that's the issue here.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: In case you are using a WPF Image element, make sure to set its Stretch property to None, so that it does not scale itself. Now when the DPI of the Source bitmap is 96, the coodrinates in the Image element are identical to pixel coordinates. If the DPI is a different from 96, you have to scale x and y values accordingly. For reference, compare PixelWidth with Width and PixelHeight with Height of the BitmapSource that is used as the Image's Source.